# my code is not working saying entrypoint.sh

Tags: docker

I don't understand why entrypoint.sh is not found whenever I run this code, below are my files.
Tried various things but none worked.

git is already correctly handling crlf to lf conversion automatically for files when I push them to a remote repository, but in this particular case I am not doing a push to a repository. Rather, I am uploading a file, using a file field on an HTML form, to a website that requires that the file have lf line returns. So I need to be able to convert this file individually.

My available potentially useful tools available on this computer would be git and Dreamweaver CC 2014.1. (I'm guessing Word, Wordpad and Notepad are not viable options but I'm open to being corrected.)

I am on Windows 7 and using git line commands.

dockerfile

```
FROM us-artifactory.com/docker-virtual/python:3.10-alpine

# Set the work dir as code in the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Set environment variables
# Prevents Python from writing pyc files to disc 
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
# Prevents Python from buffering stdout and stderr
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Use ARG to declare build arguments
ARG username
ARG password

# Copy only the dependencies file first
COPY ./pyproject.toml .

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install poetry -i https://$username:$password@us-artifactory.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-virtual/simple --trusted-host us-artifactory.com
RUN poetry config http-basic $username $password
RUN poetry install

# Copy the rest of the application files
COPY . .

# add entrypoint.sh
COPY entrypoint.sh .
RUN pwd
RUN ls -latr
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

RUN echo "********************Debug*****************"

# run entrypoint.sh
RUN ls -latr
RUN cat entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    image: pr-auto-remediation-api
    build: 
      context: ./src
      args:
        - username=xxx
        - password=xxx
    command: poetry run start
    volumes:
      # Without this, you would have to re-build the image each time you make a change to the code.
      - ./src:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 8004:8000
  # db:
  #   build:
  #     context: ./src/db
  #     dockerfile: Dockerfile
  #   expose:
  #     - '5432'
  #   environment:
  #     POSTGRES_USER: postgres
  #     POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Waiting for postgres..."

while ! nc -z db 5432; do
  echo "..."
  sleep 0.1
done

echo "PostgreSQL started"

exec "$@"
```

And my project structure is

api
--src
--db
-- dockerfile
-- create.sql
--dockerfile
--entrypoint.sh
--docker-compose.yaml

Comment: Your volume mapping onto `/usr/src/app` hides everything in that directory in the image and replaces it with the contents of your `./src` directory on the host. Since there's no entrypoint.sh file in the ./src directory, there also isn't one in /usr/src/app in the container.

Answer (score 0):

Try this project layout:

```
├── app
│   └── script.py
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
└── entrypoint.sh
```

Both `Dockerfile` and `entrypoint.sh` are located the project root folder.

I have stripped down your files to contain (IMHO) the core details.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine

COPY entrypoint.sh /

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

That copies `entrypoint.sh` onto the image and sets the working directory. Since you want the contents of the working directory to be dynamic (you're mounting them from a volume), they will not be copied across onto the image at build time.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    image: pr-auto-remediation-api
    build: 
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./app:/usr/src/app
  db:
    image: postgres:latest 
    expose:
      - '5432'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
```

`entrypoint.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/sh

echo "Waiting for PostgreSQL..."

while ! nc -z db 5432; do
  echo "..."
  sleep 0.1
done

echo "PostgreSQL started."
```

Build and run.

```bash
docker-compose build && docker-compose up
```

[image]